# Categorical independent variables for logistic regression

Tags: logistic, nonlinear-regression, multinomial-logit

I'm currently struggling to find a appropriate method to analyze my experiment.

Currently, I have 4 groups of subjects, and each subjects made a choice between 3 options(A or B or No choice). Below table shows a portion of my data.

| Group | Choice |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 4 | A |
| 3 | No choice |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | A |

My hypothesis is that, being in group 4 makes subjects shift choice from B to A.
But I'm confused because there's 4 groups on a single category of independent variable and they're  not ordinal.

Will it be right to shift my data as below..

| Group1 | Group2 | Group3 | Group4 | Choice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| O | X | X | X | A |
| X | O | X | X | A |
| X | O | X | X | B |
| X | X | X | O | A |
| X | X | O | X | No choice |
| O | X | X | X | A |
| X | X | X | X | A |

..and use (multinomial) logistic regression to predict choice (A or B or Nochoice) from group number? I am thinking of seeing the effect of "being on group4" on increase of number of A choices in baseline of reference to choice B.

Comment: Do you need all 4 binary variables to encode 1 of 4 groups? Can it lead to any problems?

Comment: I have the same question. I'm not sure if such approach would be correct. It would be great if there's a way to use single variable to encode all 4 groups.

Comment: And I also wanted to show that group 1,2,3 all does not show such effect observed from group 4.

Comment: How would you do it if you had a continuous $y$ variable?

Comment: I suggest you search for and read about one-hot encoding. The issue you are concerned about is commonly discussed, and there is nothing special in your problem. _"It would be great if there's a way to use single variable to encode all 4 groups"_ - why would it be great? On the contrary, you wrote that group number is not ordinal, so encoding it with a single scalar is inappropriate. If you want, you can always regard several scalars (binary or continuous) as a single vector variable, which takes values within a certain range.

Comment: I was worried for multicollinearity problem that occurs if I use such approach, but after searching for on-hot encoding I realized it could be solved by removing one independent variable (such as group1). Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: @Dave I'm no expert, but I think I would have used multinomial logistic regression with just one (continuous) independent variable to predict dependent variable (choice in my case).

Comment: @RoasClack Multinomial logistic regression had a categorical, not continuous, $y$ variable, but it seems like dropping a category solved your problem. Perhaps you could post a self-answer to “close out” this question.

Comment: @Dave Oh I think I misread "y variable" as "x variable". Sorry for the confusion.  If "y" was continuous, I think I would use linear (or logistic) regression using one-hot encoding. And yes, if I'll do a bit more research and self-answer my question. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to comments, I found out that making "Group" variable to 4 dummy variables (as in the question) was called "one-hot encoding", and I could make a multinomial logistic model using these dummy variables to predict choice.

- Group 1 + Group 2 + Group 3 + Group 4 ---(predict)---> Choice

However, I noticed that using "one-hot encoding" method as above could cause [Dummy Variable Trap](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/one-hot-encoding-categorical-variables-what-is-it-why-is-it-how-is-it-6fd9ed3a161) leading to multicollinearity problem . And it could be handled by dropping one of the dummy variables. For example, I can drop Group 1.

- Group 2 + Group 3 + Group 4 ---(predict)---> Choice

Please correct me if I got this wrong.

Comment: I'd call software good statistical software if it handles redundancy of dummy (indicator) predictors for you. You shouldn't need to do it for yourself. That view is consistent with the idea that you should also be able to choose which indicator to omit.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I manged to use R for one-hot encoding.